# php check if file exist

Tags: php

can someone guide me on how to do checking to tell if file already exist in database or not before we upload it?

i wanna upload a file into database, but before it save, i want to check whther file already exist first. if yes then dont do the insert execution.

i used this [reference](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx) on uplaoding a files.

thank you very much.

Comment: How are you storing the file in the database? What criteria would signal that the file already exists? Filenames? Filesize? Binary diff of the file itself?

Comment: storing filename n filesize..thx

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but have you used PHP's built in function, file_exists(ABSOLUTE-PATH-TO-FILE)?

```
$exists = file_exists('myfile.doc');
if(!$exists) {
// do your processing
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

If you're checking the database, then just query whatever column might hold your file, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM my-table WHERE my-column = 'my-uploaded-file-name';
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the article you linked to, a file is considered as "uploaded to the database" when this query has been executed :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
```

Which means a way to check if a file "has been uploaded to the database" would be to check, when a file is being uploaded, if there is already an entry in the DB with the same name, file, type, and content that the current one.

I suppose such an entry could be fetched using a query like this one :

```
select *
from upload
where name = '$fileName'
    and size = '$fileSize'
    and type = '$fileType'
    and content = '$content'
```

If that query returns a result, your file probably already is "in the database".

BTW : To avoid checking the content of the whole file, a solution might be to add a new column to your upload table, to store some kind of hash of the file *(see [`md5`](http://php.net/md5) and/or [`sha1`](http://php.net/sha1) for instance)*.

BTW 2 : you should read a bit about [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), before using the code presented in this article without really understanding it : the following portion of code, copy/pasted from the "*code for downloading files*" section, is quite frightening, for instance :

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content " .
         "FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";
```